# On xml file download, a new line is added to start of the file

Tags: php, xml, slim, kml

I successfully generated a xml file to be use for google earth. 
It looks like this when I open the file. The file starts at line 1 [Xml generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5XF0.jpg)

I then generate a link for users to download the file. The files now starts at line 2. 
[File download from the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTNQf.jpg).

I can't figure why this is happening. 
Here's the code I used to send the file to the user.

```
     $target_file =  "../files/google.xml";
      $fh = fopen($target_file, 'r');
      $file_stream = new Stream($fh);

    return $response ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml; charset=utf-8')
                  ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/force-download')
                ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/download')
                ->withHeader('Content-Description', 'File Transfer')
                ->withHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' . basename($target_file) . '"')
                ->withHeader('Expires', '0')
                ->withHeader('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0')
                ->withHeader('Pragma', 'public')
               ->withBody($file_stream);
```

Can someone please pinpoint me to why this is happening ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever is in your file before the `<?php` tag, that is output to the browser. Check that the file doesn't have any whitespace at the beginning - line breaks, BOM marks, Unicode non-breaking spaces, nothing. The same goes for any include()d or require()d files.

Comment: Thank you.. I haven't any space or line break yet, but I am double check this. I am using twig for my templates, I don't know if it adds a line break by default so for now, still double checking if there's any white space or line breaks

Comment: The line break before the php was in the file calling all the controllers. I would have never found it you didn't precise any include or required files.  Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome. I've been bitten by this bug more than once, myself ;)